# Is there any way of checking if an enum has an object value defined in it?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn-code-analysis

Here is the enum that I have defined:

```
enum LogicalChange
{
    List = SyntaxKind.List,
    TildeToken = SyntaxKind.TildeToken,
    ExclamationToken = SyntaxKind.ExclamationToken,
    DollarToken = SyntaxKind.DollarToken,
    PercentToken = SyntaxKind.PercentToken,
    CaretToken = SyntaxKind.CaretToken,
    AmpersandToken = SyntaxKind.AmpersandToken,
    AsteriskToken = SyntaxKind.AsteriskToken,
    MinusToken = SyntaxKind.MinusToken,
    PlusToken = SyntaxKind.PlusToken,
    EqualsToken = SyntaxKind.EqualsToken
}
```

I have a set of commands that should execute only if `change.After.Parent.Kind()` (which returns a `SyntaxKind`) is defined in the enum `LogicalChange`.

What I have tried so far is -
`Enum.IsDefined(typeof(LogicalChange), change.After.Parent.Kind())`
but this generates an exception. I don't want to do string comparison. Is there any other way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a simple name or string comparison, you need to cast it to the Enum Type you are comparing it to. This should not trigger an exception:

```
if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(LogicalChange), (LogicalChange)change.After.Parent.Kind()))
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IsDefined method allows to you to send three type as value:

1. own enum type
2. int
3. string

so you can use these ways:

```
 1. Enum.IsDefined(typeof(LogicalChange), (LogicalChange)change.After.Parent.Kind())
 2. Enum.IsDefined(typeof(LogicalChange), (int)change.After.Parent.Kind())
 3. Enum.IsDefined(typeof(LogicalChange), change.After.Parent.Kind().ToString())
```

- note: way no 3 is correct for you because you choose same name in both Enums, But it's better to not use it.